# What are the p2p technologies out there?

Tags: webcam, p2p, rtmfp

I want to develop a web-based application for my employer. The application will allow users to chat face to face using their webcam. I was really interested in rtmfp until I discovered that it is only good for one or two way conferencing according to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html which means that only two people will be able to chat with each other just as chatroulette. But I want a multiple way conferencing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at WebRTC.  I haven't tried it, but here's the first multiuser demo that I'm aware of: https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io

Some discussion about it (and how I know of the project) can be found in the webrtc-discuss Google Group at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/discuss-webrtc/26UNDNm-q0w/discussion

For more information about WebRTC in general, see also:

- http://www.webrtc.org/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I saw it too but the problem with it is that it uses some sort of javascript api which will make it open to everybody. The other problem that I have with it is that it is not ready as flash rtmfp. It is not supported by all browsers as of now. But thanks for your input though.